# "Yahtzee" game Java Programming

Tags: java

My assignment is to make "Yahtzee" game on Java Program. 
I am almost done except the Small Straight method. (Cannot figure it out.)

Small Straight is when the dice got 4 straight number. (Ex. 12334, 23345, 34556, and etc.)

Here is my code of isSmallStraight method (This code is not completed!):

```
public static boolean isSmallStraight(List<Die> dice) {

        boolean result = false;

        List<Die> copy = new ArrayList<Die>(dice);
        Collections.sort(copy);

        List<Die> testCase1 = new ArrayList<Die>();
        testCase1.add(new Die(1));
        testCase1.add(new Die(2));
        testCase1.add(new Die(3));

        if(copy.containsAll(testCase1)) {
            result = true;
            System.out.println(result);
        }

        return result;

    }
```

What I want to do in here is I passed 5 random numbers of dice from the main method (List dice) and put them into the "copy" object.
Since I need to use java.util.List.containsAll() method(requirement), I think I need to make one other object "testCase1" to compare with "copy". (If you have other method to solve this question, it is fine at least you use java.util.containsAll() method.)

However, what I don't know right now is if I use dice.add(new Die(3)), it means the program picks random numbers from 1,2, and 3. (Not die number 3) - Also, it gave me compile-time error.

So, I want to know how I can store dice specific number 1,2,3, and 4 for "testCase1", 2,3,4, and 5 for "testCase2", and 3,4,5, and 6 for "testCase3" and use copy.containsAll(testCase1) becomes true.

Please help me as soon as possible!

PS. Die class is already programmed by my professor. (So, cannot change any in the Die class).

Comment: Putting _ASAP!_ on an `SO` posting is like a magnet for downvotes

Answer (score 5):

Put the numbers into a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) to get rid of duplicates and get sorting for free.

You have 4 straight dice if:

1. The set contains exactly 4 numbers
2. The difference between the largest and the smallest is 3

Comment: Can you write in code, please? I cannot understand by words... lol

Comment: Great solution! I'm sure you can find some examples of TreeSet with numbers on the Web.

Comment: TreeSet<Die> testCase1 = new TreeSet<Die>(4);
testCase1.add(1);
testCase1.add(2);
testCase1.add(3);
testCase1.add(4);

Is this you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

The method I like to use (for large and small straights as well as all other scoring) is to create a new int array from the int array that holds the dice values. Like this:

```
int[] numDice = new int[6];
for (int i: diceValues)
    numDice[i-1] += 1;
```

This counts up all your dice and puts the number of each, in order, in a new array. For instance, if the 5 dice you rolled were 3, 4, 3, 1, and 6, your new array would be {1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1}, and a yahtzee of all 4s would turn into {0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0}. From this new array it's fairly trivial to determine all of the scores. For straights:

```
int straightCount = 0;
for (int i: numDice) {
    if (i > 0)
        straightCount++;
    else
        straightCount = 0;
    if (straightCount > 3)
        smallStraight = true;
    if (straightCount > 4)
        largeStraight = true;
}
```

If you wanted to you could use this array to easily determine all the valid scores in one short method, and store the booleans in a single array.